# What are my options for estimating probabilities of success/failure?

Tags: probability, modeling

So, I want to estimate the probability that a student will succeed or fail in a particular major (suppose success means in this case to graduate with that major) based on data from that student's application. I have a lot of records of past students' application data and success.

I am aware that I could try logistic regression, but I would like to know all my options, including methods which allow more easily for non-linearities.

If I were just trying to classify incoming students, I think I would try an SVM model. But I don't know how easy it is to adapt that method to the task of estimating probabilities.

#### EDIT:

Much of the data is categorical. Often binary. Some features are real numbers / integers, as well.

Comment: What kind of data- continuous? binary features? (FWIW, it's almost always worth it to try logistic regression first before trying other alternatives).

Comment: What are your covariates and what assumptions are you willing to make about the available student data (e.g. independence from one student to the next, dependent on additive functions of the covariates, independent additive error component for the model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider classification trees. You don't say what software you are using, but there are several ways to do this in R, which is free. I personally have used the party() package with good results, but that's not to say other packages aren't just as good.

A classification tree is often very good at finding various interactions. You wind up with different sets of the IVs and the probability of "success" on your DV for different combinations.